# Testing Modal props with enzyme and jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a modal component that is shared all through out the application. I'm trying to test that the modal renders with everything inside it?
I get an error saying that non of the classes are in the modal. Not sure why?

This is my code for the modal:

```
import FocusTrap from 'focus-trap-react';
import React from 'react';
import { FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';

const Modal = (props) => {
  const { onClickClose, title, content, active, footer } = props;

  return active ? (
    <FocusTrap>
      <div className="gcs_modal__background">
        <div className="gcs_modal">
          <div className="gcs_modal__header">
            <div className="gcs_modal__icon">
              <FaTimes
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  onClickClose();
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <h1 className="gcs_modal__title">{title}</h1>
          </div>

          <div className="gcs_modal__content">{content}</div>

          <div className="gcs_modal__footer">{footer}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </FocusTrap>
  ) : null;
};

export default Modal;
```

This is what I have so far on my test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow , render} from 'enzyme';
import Modal from '../Modal'

const modal = <Modal/>

describe('Modal', () => {
    it('render the modal', () => {
        shallow(modal)
    })
    it('has a background', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(modal)
        expect(wrapper.find('.gcs_modal__background')).toHaveLength(1);
        // expect(wrapper.find('.gcs_modal__background').children()).toHaveLength(2);
    })
})
```

The error i get is; expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)
Expected length: 1
Received length: 0
Received object: {}

Comment: In `Modal`, don't you want to have `active = true`? I don't see that being set in the test, so I'd assume you just don't get any HTML for it.

Comment: Right! Good observartion @VLAZ
How can I implement that into my test?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how you initialise JSX components. I would assume it's `<Modal active="true" />` but I might be wrong. Whatever the way to pass props to a component is - that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `active` prop. Otherwise your component will render nothing (return `null` and therefore `wrapper.find('.gcs_modal__background')` will have a length of zero)

This should work:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow , render} from 'enzyme';
import Modal from '../Modal'

const modal = <Modal/>

describe('Modal', () => {
    it('render the modal', () => {
        shallow(modal)
    })
    it('has a background', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Modal active={true} />)
        expect(wrapper.find('.gcs_modal__background')).toHaveLength(1);
        // expect(wrapper.find('.gcs_modal__background').children()).toHaveLength(2);
    })
})
```